# Image appears only after scroll TableView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, sdwebimage

I have TableView with several text fields and image. For Image loading I use SDWebImage Library.

Here is code for TableView Source

```
public class ExperienceSource : UITableViewSource
{

    //UINavigationController instance, to pass it to constructor
    private UINavigationController primNav { get; set; }
    private UITableView tableView { get; set; }
    List<Experience> TableItems;
    ExperienceTableViewController owner;
    public ExperienceSource(List<Experience> items,ExperienceTableViewController owner, UINavigationController nav)
    {
        TableItems = items;
        this.owner = owner;
        primNav = nav;
    }


    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {

        if (TableItems.Count == 0)
        {


            var noDataLabel = new UILabel
            {
                Text = "No Experiences at your location at this time. Try to change destination",
                TextColor = UIColor.Black,
                TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
                LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap,
                Lines = 0
            };
            tableview.BackgroundView = noDataLabel;
            tableview.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;

            return TableItems.Count;
        }
        else
        {
            tableview.BackgroundView = null;
            tableview.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;
            return TableItems.Count;
        }


    }

    public override async void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var selectedExperience = await ExperienceMethods.GetSelectedTour(TableItems[indexPath.Row].id);
        if (selectedExperience == "Saved")
        {
        ExperienceDetailViewController ExperienceDetailController = primNav.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ExperienceDetailViewController") as ExperienceDetailViewController;
        primNav.PushViewController(ExperienceDetailController, true);

        }
        else
        {
          UIAlertController okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create("", "Cannot select this experience", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        okAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
        }
        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
    }


    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("cell_id", indexPath) as ExperienceCell;
        Experience item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];
        cell.UpdateCell(item);
        return cell;
    }
}
```

And here is code for CustomCell

```
public partial class ExperienceCell : UITableViewCell
{
    UIImage picture;
    public ExperienceCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }
    internal void UpdateCell(Experience experience)
    {
            var image_url = "https://xplorpal.com/" + experience.cover_image.img_path + "/150x150/" + experience.cover_image.img_file;
            /*using (var url = new NSUrl(image_url))
            using (var data = NSData.FromUrl(url))
            picture = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
            ExperienceImage.Image = picture;*/
            ExperienceImage.SetImage(NSUrl.FromString(image_url),
                                       UIImage.FromBundle("placeholder"),
                                       SDWebImageOptions.RefreshCached);
            ExperienceTitle.Text = experience.title;
            ExperiencePrice.Text = "$" + experience.price;
    }
    }
```

My problem, that images appears in UIImage only after scrolling, or go to another ViewController and after, going back.

If I use commented code vs `NSUrl` etc. All okay.

Where can be my problem? Why images not appears, when I using SDWebImage?

Thank's for help.

Comment: First thing is to check the thread. use `assert(Thread.isMainThread)`

Comment: Where I need to use this? @CZ54

Comment: first line of `UpdateCell` func ?

Comment: Maybe you mean `if (NSThread.Current.IsMainThread)
{cell.UpdateCell(item);}` in GetCell method?  @CZ54

Comment: Fells like it using main Thread @CZ54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table Views with large number of rows display only a small fraction of their  total items at a given time.It's efficient for table views to ask for only the cells for row that are being displayed
Therefor on scrolling the table view, the cells get re-used and the data within the cell is repopulated.

Since you are using a downloaded image it appears to be slow.

You can try loading the image of the  exact size as the image view within the cell.

[Apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html)

[Optimizing table view performance](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/smooth-scrolling-in-uitableview-and-uicollectionview-a012045d77f)