# Image not loading until you scroll table View

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have Xamarin.iOS project, where is I use TableView

Here is tableView source code

```
 public class ExperienceSourceNew: UITableViewSource
{
    private UINavigationController primNav { get; set; }
    private UITableView tableView { get; set; }
    List<Experience> TableItems;
    ExperienceViewControllerNew _owner;
    static NSString cellIdentifier = new NSString("newcell_id");
    public ExperienceSourceNew(List<Experience> items, ExperienceViewControllerNew owner, UINavigationController nav)
    {
        TableItems = items;
        _owner = owner;
        primNav = nav;
    }
    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {

        if (TableItems.Count == 0)
        {


            var noDataLabel = new UILabel
            {
                Text = "No Experiences at your location at this time. Try to change destination",
                TextColor = UIColor.Black,
                TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
                LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap,
                Lines = 0
            };
            tableview.BackgroundView = noDataLabel;
            tableview.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;

            return TableItems.Count;
        }
        else
        {
            tableview.BackgroundView = null;
            tableview.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;
            return TableItems.Count;
        }


    }

    public override async void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var selectedExperience = await ExperienceMethods.GetSelectedTour(TableItems[indexPath.Row].id);
        if (selectedExperience == "Saved")
        {
            ExperienceDetailViewController ExperienceDetailController = primNav.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ExperienceDetailViewController") as ExperienceDetailViewController;
            primNav.PushViewController(ExperienceDetailController, true);

        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertController okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create("", "Cannot select this experience", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            okAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
        }
        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);

    }


    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = (ExperienceCellNew)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier, indexPath);
        Experience item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];
        cell.UpdateCell(item);
        return cell;
    }
```

I use custom Cell for TableView, so here is code for it

```
public ExperienceCellNew (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {

    }
    internal void UpdateCell(Experience experience)
    {
        var image_url = "https://xplorpal.com/" + experience.cover_image.img_path + "/150x150/" + experience.cover_image.img_file;
        ExperienceTitleNew.Text = experience.title;
        ExperiencePriceNew.Text = "$" + experience.price;
        NSUrlSession session = NSUrlSession.SharedSession;
        var dataTask = session.CreateDataTask(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(image_url)), (data, response, error) =>
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
                {
                    ExperienceImageNew.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
                });
            }
        });

        dataTask.Resume();
    }
}
```

My problem, that images not appears on View load, I have text in labels, but don't have images. If I scroll TableView, images are appears in cells.

Where can be problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table Views with large number of rows display only a small fraction of their total items at a given time.It's efficient for table views to ask for only the cells for row that are being displayed Therefor on scrolling the table view, the cells get re-used and the data within the cell is repopulated.

Since you are using a downloaded image it appears to be slow.

You can try loading the image of the exact size as the image view within the cell.

[This is  similar to your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178226/image-appears-only-after-scroll-tableview/54228489#54228489)

And also assigning the image to imageview on main thread and make it synchronous as UI changes require synchronous access to main thread.

Comment: What you mean - exact size?

Comment: If the image view is of 50x50 px then loading 1024x1024 would be unneccessary and take more time to load and display, therefore choosing the  size  which is nearest to the image view size would fasten the process.

Comment: It's already min size. My problem is in loading image. It appears only after scroll. How it connect with image size?

I try different size of images, so I think it not related to this.


When I use this code not in tableview, in simple view with uiimage , all downloads great and image appears without scroll, or smth.

Comment: The tableview does not load all the images for all the cells at once. The images are downloaded when the cells are created .Since the cells are dynamic , they are created only as many as required to fill the screen. For example if four cells fill the screen only four to five cells are created at the start. Only when you start scrolling the other cells get created and that is when the images are downloaded . Since the download begins after you have scrolled , the images take time to load. You can try adding a local default image till the actual image gets downloaded

Comment: Okay. When I have only one cell on screen, I see same problem.

Comment: I set the breakpoint on code for the image, it hits, but I don't see an image. When I scroll, it hits the second time and image appears.

Comment: Do you mean this part of the code  :var dataTask = session.CreateDataTask(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(image_url)), (data, response, error) =>
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
                {
                    ExperienceImageNew.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
                });
            }
        });

Comment: Can you try using dispatchSync instead of DispatchAsync ??

Comment: It heps I think. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) which will let you do this

```
ImageService.LoadUrl(image_url).Into(ExperienceImageNew);
```

Comment: I was trying to use it, same thing. Images not appears in until scroll. My problem, I cannot understood, why